# Is there a way to test that a Java method does not throw a specific type of exception?

Tags: java, junit

I am just looking at assertDoesNotThrow() in the JUnit documentation [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.3.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertDoesNotThrow(org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable)). I know that you can specify the type of exception with assertThrows() but it appears from the documentation that you cannot do that with assertDoesNotThrow(). Is there a particular reason for that? If you wanted to show that, for example, a method does not throw a ParseException, how would you go about doing that?

Edit: I should have put "does not throw a ParseException when given a particular argument e.g. "hello".

Comment: The method asserts that *no* exceptions are thrown. If no exceptions are thrown, it definitely isn't throwing a ParseException.

Comment: That is possible to do with [assertj](https://assertj.github.io/doc/): `assertThatCode(...).satisfiesAnyOf(t -> assertThat(t).isNull(),t -> assertThat(t).isNotInstanceOf(ParseException.class));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *default* for a Java test is that it asserts that the function doesn't throw.  You don't need to do any extra work for that; you only need to do extra work to allow it to throw.

To test that a method does not throw a `ParseException`, run it.  That's all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. "You only need to do extra work to allow it to throw", could spell out what you mean a bit here please? This is day one of learning about testing for me.

Comment: If you want to check that a function fails with an exception, you need to do some work to make that happen.  If you want to check that a function _doesn't_ fail with an exception, you don't have to do anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to prove a method does not throw exception is like saying purple unicorns don't exist. One has to check every spot in the universe to prove that. On the other hand if you check the spots where purple unicorns might live and don't see any of them, you can *approximate* and tell they don't exist in this context.

So while testing methods to see if they behave as expected, you test edge cases, boundary conditions. And for some of those cases you expect your method to throw exceptions, hence the `assertThrows()`.

Other than that it's not possible/meaningless to try to prove a method does not throw exceptions in Java. Because you can't prove a method is pure, i.e. it will behave exactly same every time you run it.

Comment: I don't think anyone is asking for proof, just a test, like a unit test.

Comment: I have added an edit to my original post.